# Paypal enrollment setting is not accessed in teacher panel of moodle site

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I enabled the paypal enrollment plugin. Now admin can set paypal enrollent for a course. But teacher panel not get this option. but all other options like manual,self etc. are available for the teacher.But when admin add this in a course,it will be available for teacher at that particular course's edit mode. I can't understand what is the wrong. Please somebody help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `enrol/paypal:config` capability is enabled(set as cap_allow) for editing teacher role, since it is enabled for manager archetype role only by default